# Angular2 typescript in Asp.Net Mvc 4, getting started

Tags: typescript, angular

I'm not sure how to get started with Angular2 in typescript, Visual Studio 2015 for Asp.Net MVC 4

I have a typescript file which includes this

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
```

I then use nuget to get angular2.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped

A compile now gives me -a lot- of errors, e.g.

```
Build: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'
```

and a few thousand of these errors

```
Build: Duplicate identifier 'SetterFn'
```

which are presumably because there are lots of versions of angular ts files present

All the answers I find on the web reference tsconfig.json and Asp.Net Mvc 5/Core

Where to start with this?

Comment: use npm and typings from npm to manage the definitelyTyped typings . Nuget lacks behind the typings to manage them . Nuget typings are always behind the original github releases

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings

Comment: I've managed to get away with not using npm up until now, if I do go down this road won't there still be multiple versions of angular2, alpha26, 28, 30, etc. how does typescript know which one to use?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `typings` install brings in two versions of the typings, so you will see browser.d.ts and main.d.ts under the typings folder.

When TypeScript sees both you get the Duplicate identifier error. This is a source of confusion IMO, but the fix is to remove one of them. Either by deleting the file (and folder with same name) or listing it as an `exclude` in your tsconfig.json.

For front end projects like Angular in the browser I would remove `main.d.ts`

Example of tsconfig exclude:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main"
  ]
}
```